# combination of "WHERE NOT EXISTS" & "SELECT 1 FROM" not working

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I've an query working in SQLite but it's not working in MySQL.

I'm using: PHP, PDO, SQLite & MySQL

Here is the query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, tag, timestamp)
    SELECT 11, 'Legio', 'LR', 1234567
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM mytable 
                WHERE id = 11 AND name = 'Legio' AND tag = 'LR' AND timestamp = (
                    SELECT max(timestamp) FROM mytable WHERE id = 11))
```

The result is an error message:

> Syntax error near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM `mytable` WHERE id = 11 AND name' at line 3.

What is wrong with this query in MySQL?

Is it possible to adapt this statement to work in MySQL and SQLite???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: I'm looking for the correct statement which is working in SQLite and MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select from a table name when using a `WHERE` clause. Since you're not actually selecting from a real table, you can use the special table name `DUAL`

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, tag, timestamp)
SELECT 11, 'Legio', 'LR', 1234567
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mytable 
    WHERE id = 11 AND name = 'Legio' AND tag = 'LR' 
        AND timestamp = (
            SELECT max(timestamp) FROM mytable WHERE id = 11))
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
SELECT 11, 'Legio', 'LR', 1234567 FROM `table_name` WHERE NOT EXISTS...
```

You missed the FROM.

Comment: I think not... I don't select these values from any table. This statement is working in SQLite.

Comment: Try it if you can, maybe it's expecting a FROM - you can have any table in that `table_name`